# Is it possible to manage spam/junk messages with Geary?

Tags: pantheon-mail

I can't seem to find any option to mark an email message as spam in Geary. Can anyone explain how to manage junk/spam messages with Geary?

Thanks

Comment: What email service(s) are you using?

Comment: Zoho, yahoo and my company email. No spam options for any of them

Comment: Gmail contains spam blocking.I do not think that Geary can do this

Answer (score 2):

Geary doesn't offer this feature, but both Yahoo and Zoho provide spam filtering on the server side. If these filters aren't catching everything, you can "train" them by dragging spam messages into the Junk folder. You can do this from Geary or any other email client.

The good thing about server-based filters is that they'll run even if your Elementary OS machine is off and you're accessing your email from your phone or the web.

https://antispam.yahoo.com/

https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/anti-spam.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, not possible via client side.

A spam filter only work server sided with geary.

Comment: That's disapointing, it's an important feature in my opinion

Comment: You may add that to the wishlist. It's possible with Thunderbird, although in my opinion Geary is way better, even if it lacks features.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the same as on Pop! OS, but assuming it is, the features are there.  They're just not visible from the UI.  You have to use the keyboard shortcuts.

> Toggle spam: Ctrl+J or !

See the bug report [Cannot mark messages as spam / not spam](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/geary/issues/60) for details.

Comment: so helpfull ! Still missing int the UI 3 years after

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking a bit. It IS possible to use client sided spam filters with geary by hosting a mail server on your pc that's configured to download the mails and then runs spamassassin. I'm sorry that I can't exactly tell you how it's done, but I'm sure there are How-To's out there. However, Ryans answer is way more practical and your pc wouldn't need to download (probably infected) mails first. Also it would only work on your pc, but not your phone etc.